# How to do syntax highlighting using highlight.js in ace editor using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ace-editor, highlight.js

I want to highlight syntax for programming languages dynamically on ace editor (as its done on Ideone).

I refered to following resouces:

https://github.com/pc035860/angular-highlightjs

http://plnkr.co/edit/OPxzDu?p=preview,

but could not implement it on ace editor.

However ideone.com also uses ace editor and uses angularjs for syntax highlighting.

According to above resources, I wrote the following code:

```
<div ui-ace hljs hljs-no-escape>                       
       #include&lt;bits/stdc++.h&gt;; using namespace std; int main() { return 0; }
</div>
```

And here is my app.js code:

```
angular.module('ace_app', ['ui.ace','hljs']);
```

***but my ace editor displays nothing.***

I am using the angularjs ace directive of: **github.com/angular-ui/ui-ace**

I think these 2 directives are conflicting: ace and hljs (highlightjs)

### *For more information, please comment.*